# What wire would I need for 24000 watts (48v @ 500amps max) of DC power?

Tags: batteries, motor, wiring

I have four batteries in series, 48v and a 500amp controller.

Right now, I am using standard amplifier battery cables, I believe they are 0 gauge.

Operational performance is not as good as suspected and the controller and wires seem to get very hot at peak amps and today a lead terminal sheared itself off under constant load.

I am guessing my wire is insufficient for carrying such a load.

If so, what should I use?

Additional information per comments:

I didn't expect to move to 500 A, I was pushing 200 A for a while and upgraded the controller. The application is a finished electric motorcycle, but I live on a mountainous area so the amperage is sustained longer than usual.

Would you recommend aluminum over copper?

The way each battery is mounted won't allow for busbars to be used.

Really hard estimate the wire length everything is mounted tight, no wire is more than 12", most being around 6"

I do notice voltage drop during higher amp loads but I think that's to be expected anyways during acceleration

The connections are made of lead, they're automotive grade electrical wire, like what connects to a starter. Fine for 200a maybe not for 500.

Comment: A simple Google search for "american wire gauge" will bring up many links containing tables. Multiple 0000 gauge cables would be required for 500A steady draw with manageable temperature rise.

Comment: How about to Google for "current capacity of copper wire" instead of guessing?

Comment: Another term to google is "bus bar".

Comment: 0 gauge can only carry about 150 amps safely. You need 900 MCM or so depending on insulation type. You also need to consider the length of the wire. Voltage drop could  be a problem if the length is too long. That seem like a lot of sustained current for just series connected batteries.

Comment: I didn't expect to move to 500a, I was pushing 200a for a while and upgraded the controller. The application is a finished electric motorcycle, but I live on a mountainous area so the amperage is sustained longer than usual.

Comment: Would you recommend aluminum over copper at this point?

Comment: wire? why not busbars...

Comment: The way each battery is mounted won't allow for busbars to be used.

Comment: I don't know. This is a motorcycle for gosh sake. How long can the wire be? At 500 A, I get about 80 watts for a full meter length of the stuff (\$323\:\mu\Omega \cdot \left(500\:\textrm{A}\right)^2\$.) Of course, that's for really good copper. And while I'm sure heavier gauge is better, I'm more worried about your connections than the wire itself. Is the heating localized?

Comment: Really hard to say, everything is mounted tight, no wire is more than 12", most being around 6"

Comment: I do notice voltage drop during higher amp loads but I think that's to be expected anyways during acceleration

Comment: The connections are made of lead, they're automotive grade electrical wire, like what connects to a starter. Fine for 200a maybe not for 500.

Comment: Rule of thumb is 1mm² per 10A. For short cables you may use less as the voltage drop is more at the connectors then.

Comment: 2/0 copper with 90C insulation is good for 195 amps. For 75C insulation you need 3/0 and 4/0 for 60C insulation. For aluminum,  it would be 4/0, 250 mcm and 300 MCM. Aluminum is cheaper and lighter, but more difficult to work with.

Comment: Note that the high temperature wire is rated for higher current, but it could run too hot for the battery and controller terminals.

Comment: @CharlesCowie: Aluminium conductors are dangerous when they are fitted wrong. Even welded aluminium contacts may fail miserably. Noone but power grid people should use aluminium conductors. They have the right tools and know what they are doing.

Comment: @Janka I wouldn't put it quite that strongly, but "difficult to work with" was an understatement. For this application, I would recommend diesel locomotive cable (DLO) or copper welding cable. If it only comes with 90C insulation, I would oversize the wire so the terminals don't get too hot.

Comment: So 4/0 copper welding cable will be sufficient? What recommendation on the connections? I don't want that to be a bottleneck afterr rewiring

Comment: You will need to search to see what terminals are available that are compatible with your batteries, controller and motor. It is likely you will need 2 or 3 kinds.

Comment: Got it all sorted. Thanks so much for all the help Charles.

Comment: If you remember, and if the solution you have chosen works well, please come back and write a detailed answer for your own question, including how you terminated the cable and what kind of connectors you used, etc.

Comment: @Charles Cowie please post as an answer and I'll mark yours as the solution

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize handling aluminium conductors is not recommended for anyone. You need spring-loaded contacts and put a special grease onto the whole arrangement to avoid corrosion. Electromigration may still happen at DC and when your contact overheats and the grease melts away you get a nice arc. This is something you generally don't want at 500A DC. Saw the result in East German electrical installations which arced at ~30A AC. The wires were all gone. (They even invented special wirenuts and a small grease pistol for it just to avoid using copper due to the shortening and price.)

Comment: This has convinced me to go higher voltage for my eventual electric-motorcycle project...

Comment: @insta even with 48v and non-optimized gearing, I am hitting 60mph, range is undetermined, but estimated between 60-80 miles per charge. (I used four 75 amp hour batteries)

Comment: High voltage has dangers of its own, but I am inclined to agree. When you get to more than 100A, the cables become ridiculous. Never built an electric vehicle, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2/0 copper with 90C insulation is good for 195 amps. For 75C insulation you need 3/0 and 4/0 for 60C insulation. Those are electrical code requirements for building wiring for conductors bundled into a cable or conduit. Ratings are based on air temperature not exceeding 86F.

I would strongly recommend copper wire. Aluminum is cheaper and lighter, but more difficult to work with. Special wire terminals are required with a special tool to attach them to the wire. Some kind of special grease needs to be applied at the termination.

For this application, I would recommend diesel locomotive cable (DLO) or copper welding cable. If it only comes with 90C insulation, I would oversize the wire so the terminals don't get too hot. Both of these types of cable are more finely stranded than typical stranded wire. That makes the wire more flexible and allows it to make better contact with terminals.

In this application, the largest part of the voltage drop is likely the internal resistance of the batteries. The voltage drop of AWG 0 wire is about 0.05 volts per foot at 200 amps. AWG 2/0 would drop about 0.04 V/ft and AWG 4/0 about 0.03 V/ft.

The voltage drop in the connections depends on the contact area, the smoothness of the contact and the pressure of the connection. The best wire terminals are probably the kind that is compressed permanently around the wire using a special tool. For wire this size, you should only use quite a good quality tool. The type of terminal that compresses the wire with a screw is easier to use. For best results, look up the torque specification for the terminal and use a torque wrench. Your controller may have that type of terminal built in, or it might have studs or holes to attach wire terminals. If the motor has leads rather than terminals, you will need screw compression wire splicers that you need to tape up to insulate the splice. Depending on the type of battery and the terminals it has, you may want to look for battery terminals that have either holes to bolt to ring terminals or compression terminals for wires. Make sure the terminals are rated for the size wire you are using and tighten them to specifications with a torque wrench.

If your controller has wire compression terminals, don’t use a larger wire than the terminals are rated for and tighten them to specifications with a torque wrench.

Here are pictures of appropriate terminals, wire splice and terminal crimping tool.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The wire and ends arrived today, and I have already begun rewiring. Thank you so much!

Comment: I rewired everything today and MANNN what a difference, the bike is a ROCKET now and no more heat issue. Your advice really helped, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are deep into busbar territory at 400 A.
You should consider multiple wires unless you want to get into very large cables.

Amp capacity of wire is generally conservatively rated at 700 circular mils per amp as in this [table](http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm).

You could use multiple automotive [primary wire](http://www.awcwire.com/part.aspx?partname=gpt-8) connections. This is good multistranded insulated wire that is flexible enough to route. You'd need 4-5 cables for 400 A continuous.

Or if you could use uninsulated cable, then automotive [earth braid](http://www.awcwire.com/part.aspx?partname=f-braid-1-3/4) might be a good choice. If your cables are only a few inches long, this might be the ideal choice as a single run would support 380 A continuous, and well over 400 A burst. You could put loose insulation covering over it.

Comment: Jack - you (or Murphy) have posted nearly identical duplicate answers.

Comment: So that's what the Post twice button does....

Comment: :-)    [Redolent Redundancies](http://bit.ly/russellrr) there, that's  > 15.

Comment: Problem already solved.

Answer (score 1):

For low voltage work, the voltage drop per length is often critical. You say it's a motorbike, so let's assume connections are 1m long. If you have a radically different length, then you can just modify my answer proportionally.

What would you consider 'good'? With 48v available, losing 1v in the wiring is 98% efficiency, probably a reasonable place to start. Of course the wires go there and back, so you want 0.5v drop per wire.

At 500A, a voltage drop of 500mV requires a wire resistance of 500m/500 = 1mohm, nice round number. As copper has a room temperature resistivity of 17mohm per 1m of 1mm2 wire (numbers I always have in my head), then you need at least 17mm2 wire, for that voltage drop.

The power being lost in each wire is 0.5V * 500A = 250 watts, which is probably excessive. So it looks like heating, and not voltage drop, is the limiting factor at 48v and this distance. Certainly the 10A/mm2 rule of thumb for low currents suggests 50mm2 area, and at 500A, we would tend to tun at less than 10A/mm2, as for a single wire, there is proportionally less surface area available for cooling. Certainly 'normal' wiring regulations would expect something like 250mm2 for a single core 500A wire.

As you increase the area, the voltage drop and therefore power dissipated falls proportionally.

If you can make the connections as a parallel set of smaller wires that are **not** bundled together, then cooling is improved, and more current can be carried.

Now we can draw up a crude table, of heating power versus cross sectional area for 1m connections at 500A. Pick a suitable pair of numbers, interpolation to standard sizes is obviously trivial.

```
area    power per wire

17mm2    250W
34mm2    125W
68mm2     63W
136mm2    32W
270mm2    16W
```

Comment: I already said no connection is more than 12"; all but two are 6"

Comment: I answered the question before you added that later. I figured if it wasn't important enough to tell us first off how long the connections were, then you wouldn't have any problem scaling them. Did you see I already said 'if 1m is wrong, then scale'?